# How do I generate var data with random attributes of circles using d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Here I have an example of a data set that I have

var Data = [
    {
        "r": 434,
        "y": 0.04,
        "x": 0.34,
    },
    {
        "r": 9770,
        "y": 0.97,
        "x": 1.70,
    },
    {
        "r": 4680,
        "y": 0.46,
        "x": 0.80,
    }

, I want to transform it into something where I Set the the data to be 20 circles, where each circle having randomly generated attributes

Answer (score 1):

You can generate random numbers with `Math.random()`. This function returns a random number between 0 and 1. You can multiply that by another number if you want to fit the number in a different range.

Here I generate an array of 20 elements:

```
var Data = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  Data.push({"r": Math.random() * 1000, "y": Math.random() / 10, "x": Math.random()});
}
console.log(Data);
```

Comment: Just as an improvement, you can drop the for loop altogether: `var data = d3.range(20).map(()=>({"r": Math.random() * 1000, "y": Math.random() / 10, "x": Math.random()}));`.